# how to add click events in bootstrap table api custom button using jQuery

Tags: bootstrap-table

I do not know how to add on click events to the custom buttons that bootstrap provides, using jQuery.

For example the data-show-export attribute will give a default button which will export the table contents but how to add on click event to it using jQuery.

```
<table
 id="table"
 data-toggle="table"
 data-show-export ="true"
 >
</table>
```

Comment: Did you try to target the table then the button: `$('table[data-show-export="true"] button')` ?

Comment: This is not working

Comment: Hi Dimitri, i tried this it dies not show error but its not working $('table[data-show-export="true"]button').click(function(){

alert("this button was clicked");
});

Answer (score 0):

You can find a full example on how to use this extension here : https://live.bootstrap-table.com/example/extensions/export.html

Otherwise you can also target the button like Dimitri said `$('table[data-show-export="true"] button')` and use a `onclick` event on it.

Comment: the second solution  given by Dimitri is a cleaner solution but it is not working can you help me with that.

Comment: $('table[data-show-export="true"]button').click(function(){

alert("this button was clicked");
});

Comment: Make sure the target is correct. It seems like you are missing a space between `table[data-show-export="true"]` and `button`. Otherwise if you are not sure how to target the button use the inspector inside your browser to target the button correctly.

Comment: By the way since your table has an id you could also use $('#table button') to target your button.